# Allow Pass By Reference at the Script Level

Tags: pass-by-reference, php

I am trying to allow a few functions that are all contained in one script to pass by reference. I don't want to turn this on globally but when I add the following directive in the script where I want pass by reference, I still see the PHP warnings:

```
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
```

I was expecting to see those warnings go away after I overrode the PHP INI file.

```
 ini_set("allow_call_time_pass_reference", "true");
```

How do I do this or is that correct and the warnings are there because the PHP interpreter is not parsing my local ini_set() directive only reading php.ini?

Comment: Warnings exist for a reason. It's probably not a good idea to rely on a deprecated feature.

Comment: Which warnings are you getting? This setting has been deprecated in php 5.x

Comment: More to the point, there is never a good reason to use "call-time pass-by-reference". It subverts the intent of the author of the function you are calling. If you have this your code is almost certainly written incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php : `allow_call_time_pass_reference` => **PHP_INI_PERDIR**
2. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php : `PHP_INI_PERDIR` => Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

Answer: you can't set it with `ini_set`.

And if you will be using php 5.4.0, this configuration option has been removed.

Comment: PHP 5.3 and I am using ini_set() in the script where I want to pass by reference. See my question

Comment: See my answer, read linked references. There is nothing more to add here.

Comment: Fair enough. I am selecting your answer due to completeness on this topic even though my exact problem was not addressed.

Comment: Of course it is addressed. This is global setting that can't be changed during runtime. And in current php version this is completely removed, so instead of trying to find solution for it you should rethink your app and not rely on this setting.